# Detect a pan over multiple objects?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

So here I have a loop that creates a bunch of different squares on the screen, using an array, and I've added a gesture recognizer to detect for a pan. The thing is, I want to be able to smoothly slide over one object to the next, without lifting my finger. But, with my current code I have to lift my finger and slide over each object individually. Does anyone know how to make it so that I can smoothly slide my finger over each object, and have them perform their functions when they've been slid over? Here's my code:

```
    int numby = [squareLocations count];

    for (int i = 0; i < numby; i++)
    {
        NSValue *pointLocation = [squareLocations objectAtIndex:i];
        CGPoint tmpPoint = [pointLocation CGPointValue];
        UIImage *theSquare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"square.png"];

        UIButton *squareButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

        squareButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        squareButton.frame = CGRectMake(tmpPoint.x, tmpPoint.y, theSquare.size.width, theSquare.size.height);
        squareButton.tag = *(&i);
        [squareButton setImage:theSquare forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *slide = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        [squareButton addGestureRecognizer:slide];

        [whereStuffActuallyHappens addSubview:squareButton];

    }

}

- (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)slide {


    [slide setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:slide.view];

    NSInteger tag = slide.view.tag;
    NSLog(@"Tag is: %i", tag);

    [slide.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A kinda hack-ish way to do this would be to add the pan gesture to the superview of your squares instead, and check which one has the location of the gesture colliding with its frame.

Comment: Is there a way to check the tags of the squares using touchesBegin ? I was thinking if I could check the tags of the squares using that, I could do it that way?

Comment: I have never been successful in getting touchesBegin to work so I may be wrong, but I don't think that it will get called if the finger is still on the screen and just goes over a view.

Comment: What if I stuffed a pan recognizer into touchesbegin?

Comment: Is there a way I could end the gesture once I finished removing the square, and start a new one without removing my finger from the screen?

Comment: You can end the gesture by seting the gesture's enabled status to NO then back to YES (ie `gesture.enabled=NO; gesture.enabled=YES`), although I have still yet to have found a way to start a gesture without a touch.

Comment: One thing you can try (I dont know if it will work. It might do nothing at all) is to set the `UIGestureRecognizerState` of the gesture on the square you are over.

Comment: I was able to solve it by making a rectangle at my finger's current location, then checking for collision against a square!